# Failed to install provider for thirdparty provider

Tags: terraform

I am using terraform modules to apply DRY principles in Azure Devops. We are using custom providers together with the official Azure Devops provider.  The modules that we have made are used so that the tf files used by the developers only serve to declare the variables since the configuration of the resources is done by the DevOps team.

The module consists of a TF file and a Variables file hosted in /modules/build_ci

**build_ci.tf:**

```
resource "build_definition_resource" "Build_CI" {
    trigger_ci      = true
    solution_name   = var.solution_name
    repository      = var.repository
    pool            = var.pool
    branch          = var.branch
    branches_ci     = var.branches_ci
    
    dynamic "build_template" {
        for_each = var.templates
        iterator = task
        content {
            name    = task.value["name"]
            input   = task.value["inputs"]
    }
    }
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "solution_name" {
    type = string
}

variable "repository" {
    type = string
}

variable "pool" {
    type    = string
    default = "alm-aws-pool"
}

variable "branch" {
    type    = string
    default = "master"
}

variable "branches_ci" {
    type    = list(string)
    default = ["master", "release/*"]
}

variable "templates" {
    type = list(object({
        name    = string
        inputs  = map(string)
    }))

    default = [
        {
            name    = "templates/build/tg1_build&nuget.yaml"
            inputs  = {
                IsNugetPrerelaseVersion = "false"
                BuildConfiguration = "Release"
                BuildPlatform = "Any CPU"
                SearchPatternToPack = "none"
            }        
        },
        {
            name    = "templates/build/TG2_Validations.yaml"
            inputs  = {
                BuildConfiguration = "Release"
            }
        },
        {
            name    = "templates/build/TG3_Publish.yaml"  
            inputs  = null      
        }
    ]
}
```

the build_template component calls yaml templates hosted in another repository.

the use of this module would be like this

```
module "app_Build_CI" {
    source          = "../modules/build_ci"
    solution_name   = "app"
    repository      = "app_repository"
}
```

and the terraform provider is:

```
provider "test_provider" {
  uri = "#{custom_provider_uri}"
  
}

provider "azuredevops" {
  org_service_url = "#{AZDO_ORG_SERVICE_URL}#"
  personal_access_token = "#{AZDO_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}#"
}

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12"
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "#{BUCKET}#"
    key    = "#{KEY}#"
    region = "#{REGION}#"
      access_key = "#{access_key}#"
      role_arn = "#{ARN_ROLE}#"
      external_id = "#{EXTERNAL_ID}#"
  }
  
  required_providers {
    test_provider = {
      versions = ["0.2"]
      source = "test/provider/test"
    }
    azuredevops = {
      source = "microsoft/azuredevops"
      version = ">=0.1.0"
    }
    repo = {
      versions = ["0.2"]
      source = "test/provider/test"
    }
    build = {
      versions = ["0.2"]
      source = "test/provider/test"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem comes when doing the terraform init, we get an error saying that it cannot install the hashichorp/build provider which we do not use. If I use the old structure without modules it works but when using modules it fails.

```
Error: Failed to install provider

Error while installing hashicorp/build: provider registry
registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/build
```

Does anyone know what this error is due to?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The error was that the modules folder must contain the provider, otherwise it takes the official hashicorp providers and not the third-party ones. That's all it takes